# Рабочий вариант с картами в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, openstreetmap

Здравствуйте.

Требуется прикрутить в десктопном приложении к списку адресов объектов отображением их на карте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, рабочие решения.
Требуется искать адрес по координатам, по адресу и назначать координате маркер.